# C - Decompress Gzipped http response

Tags: c, http, sockets, gzip, gnu

I have few issues in decompressing gzipped http response, I separated data part from headers but its gzip header and message contain \0 characters which char * takes as null terminator so the first question is how to extract gzipped chunk ?

I can't use string functions like strcat, strlen because it is compressed gzipped data that contains \0 character at various places within chunk.

I've used libcurl but it is relatively slower than C sockets.

Here is some part of a sample response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR IND"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 12605
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 11:46:30 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: _FP=EM=1; expires=Wed, 05-Mar-2014 11:46:29 GMT; domain=.bing.com; path=/

����ՠ����AU��o�
```

**Sample code:**

```
#define MAXDATASIZE 1024

char *recvData; // Holds entire gzip data
char recvBuff[MAXDATASIZE]; // Holds gzip chunk
int offset=0;
while(1){
    recvBytes = recv(sockfd, &recvBuff, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);
    totalRecvBytes += recvBytes;

    // get content length, this runs first time only as required
    if(!clfnd){
        regi = regexec(&clregex, &recvBuff, 3, clmatch, 0);
        if(!regi){
            strncpy(clarr, recvBuff + clmatch[2].rm_so, clmatch[2].rm_eo-clmatch[2].rm_so);
            clarr[clmatch[2].rm_eo-clmatch[2].rm_so] = '\0';
            cl = atoi(clarr);
            clfnd=1;
            regfree(&clregex);
            recvData = malloc(cl * sizeof(char));
            memset(recvData, 0, sizeof recvData);
        }
    }

    // get data part from 1st iteration, furthur iterations contain only data
    if(!datasplit){
        int strtidx;
        char *datastrt = strstr(&recvBuff, "\r\n\r\n");
        if(datastrt != NULL){
            strtidx = datastrt - recvBuff + 4;
            memcpy(recvData, recvBuff + strtidx, recvBytes-strtidx);
            datasplit=1;
            offset = recvBytes-strtidx;
        }
    }
    else{
        memcpy(recvData + offset, recvBuff, recvBytes);
        offset += recvBytes;
    }
    if (offset >= cl)
        break;
}

char *outData = malloc(offset*4 * sizeof(char));
memset(outData, 0, sizeof outData);
int ret = inf(recvData, offset, outData, offset*4);
```

*Inflate function:*

```
int inf(const char *src, int srcLen, const char *dst, int dstLen){
z_stream strm;
strm.zalloc=NULL;
strm.zfree=NULL;
strm.opaque=NULL;

strm.avail_in = srcLen;
strm.avail_out = dstLen;
strm.next_in = (Bytef *)src;
strm.next_out = (Bytef *)dst;

int err=-1, ret=-1;
err = inflateInit2(&strm, MAX_WBITS+16);
if (err == Z_OK){
    err = inflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
    if (err == Z_STREAM_END){
        ret = strm.total_out;
    }
    else{
        inflateEnd(&strm);
        return err;
    }
}
else{
    inflateEnd(&strm);
    return err;
}
inflateEnd(&strm);
printf("%s\n", dst);
return err;
}
```

Comment: You have some major problems here... You allocate and clear recvData for every packet you receive, which 1) makes you leak memory and 2) means that the final recvData contains a bunch of zeroes and then the last packet. Also I think your use of offset is funky, it's not updated for the first packet.

Comment: Oops... 1) program allocates memory to recvData only once, basically while copying code to SO I forgot to copy that condition so there is no problem there, see updated code 2) offset is temporarily set to 3, it is only used in second memcpy() first memcpy() does not require it, reason for writing 2 memcpy() is that I split header from data in first memcpy()'s IF condition so offset must be set to the number of data bytes excluding header bytes i.e offset=recvBytes-strtidx; but the problem is with first memcpy() it is not copying \0 chars it only copies 3 chars from recvBuff's gzipped data.

Comment: Now program decompresses http response ! memcpy() was copying \0 chars but eclipse debugger was not showing entire gzip chunk and was breaking at \0. Updated the above code.

Comment: Calculating the offset properly made it work? :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, but now there is another problem, I copied same code to my actual project, zlib's **inflateInit2()** function failed to decompress large size web page like 180 KB, only decompressed small web page like 36 KB, debugger's Backtrace showed that inflateInit2() internally called malloc() that produced this exception though there is no link-list in my program: _glibc detected: corrupted double-linked list._ It's strange that sample program decompress both small and large web pages but acutal program only decompresses small web page. Any solution ?

Comment: See code at top where 'char *outData' is written, when I malloc()ed it at same position i.e after getting complete gzipped data, in my actual program, it returned _glibc detected: corrupted double-linked list_ exception that's due to malloc() but when I temporarily malloc()ed it above while loop, it allocated space but then it threw same exception at _zlib's inflateInit2()_ function that internally called malloc().

Comment: You're allocating 4 times the space of the compressed data, are you certain that the decompressed data will fit into that? I'm sure zlib has some ways for you to handle if the decompressed data is bigger than the buffer you provided it.

Comment: Yes, the 4 times space is for 36 KB web page in sample program, I changed it to a higher value in actual program but no luck, I confirmed the sizes of both small and large web pages by retreiving them first as plain text and then as gzipped. Also, zlib returns -5 i.e buffer error if there is not enough space for decompressed data. Something else is problematic.

Comment: In actual program I was extracting cookies too just the way I extracted content length and was freeing the regular expressions using regfree(), when I moved all regfree()s to the bottom of the function it decompressed web pages but then it gave exception at **gnutls_global_init()** which I used for HTTPS GET/POST: **glibc detected: realloc(): invalid next size.** Backtrace showed that gnutls_global_init() called _gnutls_ext_register() which then called realloc() and returned this exception.

Comment: I'll try to have a look during the day. However, I think you're trying to do too much in one function. Split up the code a little, making smaller functions that does one thing right makes it easier to spot the mistakes. (And makes the code easier to read when you need to fix it two years from now :)

Comment: Solved, the problem was **not** with **gnutls_global_init()** but was caused by writing more data than its size to a PostData buffer present in a generalized function that forms GET/POST http request by taking few parameters as input. Thanks !

Comment: Good you found out. Take a look at valgrind, it may help you track town memory bugs like these.

Answer (score 4):

No, the type `char *` says nothing about the contents it points to, nor does it interpret any value as a terminator. The str* functions, on the other hand has an assumption about how strings are represented, and can not be used on binary data, or even text data that has a different representation.

Decompression can be rather complex, but you can have a look at [zlib](http://zlib.net/), whcih should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried zlib to decompress, it returns -3 i.e data error because it is not getting correct gzipped input.

Comment: How do you pass the data to zlib?

Comment: I have an inflate function which decompresses entire data part in one go though we can decompress chunk by chunk, but the problem is how to pick that one data chunk ? When I use strtok() to split at \r\n it returns 3 gzipped characters from first recv() iteration instead of returning rest of the chunk, similarly in rest of the calls to recv() it breaks at \0 and doesn't return complete chunk. When debugged, eclipse showed there are 7 \0 characters after those 3 characters which i guess are part of gzip header then other non-zero characters.

Comment: You can not use the str* functions to parse binary data. As @snibu says, you have to pass the complete buffer to zlib. See memcpy as one way of copying binary data from one buffer to another.

Answer (score 2):

Content-Length: 12605 means that the gzipped file has a size of 12605 bytes. So just copy 12605 bytes after the message header to a local buffer and give that buffer to the decompression function. Also I am not sure if your socket reading function reads the whole 12605 in one flow. If not, you need to append the rest of the data in the next read to this local buffer and when 12605 bytes are read and then call the decompression function.
There is no problem in using char* as buffer. The issue ur facing is because ur trying to print the gzip data as string.

Comment: I'm not printing gzip data, that was just to show you people. Currently the program reads 12605 bytes in iterations of 2048 bytes not in one go, unable to append gzipped data it gets truncated when it encounters \0 in the middle of data, I guess temporarily I have to increase the size of buffer to 12605 ?

Comment: `char buf[12605];
int offset = 0;

do {
    recv_len = recv(socket, &recv_data, 2048, 0);

    if(recv_len > 0 ) {

 /* copying the data to buffer and incrementing the offset to copy the next received block of data*/
     memcpy(buf+offset, recv_data, recv_len); 
     offset = offset+recv_len;
    }

} while (recv_len > 0);`

Hope this helps

Comment: @Coder, show us the code, and we'll probably be able to help. Sounds like you're still trying to use string functions on binary data, though.

Comment: I updated the question, code's first memcpy() only copies first 3 chars from recvBuff, although it contains much gzipped data.     memcpy(recvData, recvBuff + strtidx, recvBytes-strtidx);

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of the HTTP payload starts after the "\r\n\r\n" (after the HTTP header).

Use the HTTP field "Content-Length" to get the HTTP payload size.

With this information, you have to create  function to decompress de data. With Zlib you can do that.

PS. pay attention if it's using raw format or zlib with header and trailers. Usualy HTTP uses header and trailer, and IMAP4 uses raw format.